# Set a timezone in react-calendar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-calendar

How do I make [react-calendar](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-calendar) return dates in a specific timezone?

Don't want to use locale for this, because of daylight savings. Need specifically the UTC timezone.

I could "convert" the returned time (usually 00:00) to be "as it was" in UTC but this seems messy.

Comment: have you tried searching their github issues

Answer (score -3):

YOU CAN TRY

"tileContent" to manipulate Calendar dates.

eg:
<Calendar
tileContent = {({ activeStartDate, date, view }) => view === 'month' && date.getDay() === 0 ?

It's Sunday!

: null} />

refer the documentation below

documentation - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-calendar?activeTab=readme

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. Where did you set the timezone in your answer?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34004195)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).